# Stretch Axis to Fit Graphics View QT Designer

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to get the x axis to fill the entire of the graphics view.

What I have now (the x axis stops around two thirds of the way of the graphics view:
[image]

what I am trying to acheive:
[image]

I have tried plot.setXRange() with zero padding but that just changes the x axis limits.

[image]
I am also unsure about why I cannot see the origin (the x and y axis does not intercept)

Just in case, here is the generated python file from QT designer.ui:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1131, 890)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.labelCh1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 100, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh1.setObjectName("labelCh1")
        self.labelCh2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 190, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh2.setObjectName("labelCh2")
        self.labelCh3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh3.setObjectName("labelCh3")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 80, 1051, 747))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetDefaultConstraint)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setHorizontalSpacing(0)
        self.gridLayout.setVerticalSpacing(7)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.PlotWidgetCh6 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh6.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh6")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh6, 5, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PlotWidgetCh5 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh5.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh5")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh5, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PlotWidgetCh2 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh2.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PlotWidgetCh7 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh7.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh7")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh7, 6, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PlotWidgetCh1 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh1.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh1")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PlotWidgetCh3 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh3.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PlotWidgetCh4 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh4.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh4, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.PlotWidgetCh8 = PlotWidget(self.layoutWidget)
        self.PlotWidgetCh8.setObjectName("PlotWidgetCh8")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.PlotWidgetCh8, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 81, 71))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../OneDrive - AB Dynamics Ltd/Desktop/brainpatch3.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.labelCh3_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh3_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 380, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh3_2.setObjectName("labelCh3_2")
        self.labelCh3_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh3_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 480, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh3_3.setObjectName("labelCh3_3")
        self.labelCh3_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh3_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh3_4.setObjectName("labelCh3_4")
        self.labelCh3_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh3_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 660, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh3_5.setObjectName("labelCh3_5")
        self.labelCh3_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.labelCh3_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 760, 31, 51))
        self.labelCh3_6.setObjectName("labelCh3_6")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(980, 10, 111, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(710, 10, 201, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 81, 71))
        self.label_3.setText("")
        self.label_3.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("logo.png"))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.numOfChBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.numOfChBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(920, 10, 51, 51))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(16)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.numOfChBox.setFont(font)
        self.numOfChBox.setObjectName("numOfChBox")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1131, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.labelCh1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 1"))
        self.labelCh2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 2"))
        self.labelCh3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 3"))
        self.labelCh3_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 4"))
        self.labelCh3_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 5"))
        self.labelCh3_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 6"))
        self.labelCh3_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 7"))
        self.labelCh3_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ch 8"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start/Stop"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Number Of Channels:"))
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: You're not setting the layout for the central widget, only for the "layoutWidget", but since that widget is *not* part of a layout, it will not be resized. Open the file again in Designer, right click on an empty area of the UI, and select a proper layout from the "lay out" submenu. See [Using layouts in Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: Thank you, editing the central widget layout fixed it